# Angular 2 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I'm having quite hard times while trying to create sample application. I just want to create hello world or re-write the Heroes app from Angular.io site, but I always fail. Is there anybody who will be able to help me?

I have VS2015 Community installed, Update 3. I'm quite new to angular and web dev, my specialization is C# .NET Win Apps.

I have already tried some tutorials but always failed. Is there anybody who is able to write down step-by-step instructions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, we can close this question, this will do the trick:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/

Comment: This only helps if he can use ASP.NET Core.